# How to improve speed of sympy.solvers for an exponential equation?

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy as part of a graph drawing program and it works pretty much perfectly for anything I throw at it, but there is one particular equation that seemed to cause it to struggle. Other exponential equations work fine, but this particular one just seems to make my code load indefinitely.

My code is as follows:

```
import math,sympy
x=sympy.Symbol("x")
print (sympy.solvers.solve(19.9*sympy.exp(-1.257*x)-275.0),x)
```

Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: Can you be more specific about the performance problems? Have you done any benchmarking or profiling?

Comment: I managed to get an answer fairly quickly with this: `sympy.solve(sympy.sympify('19.9')*sympy.exp(-sympy.sympify('1.257')*x)-275, x)`. But it actually gave me a list of solutions that's is full of imaginary numbers and looks absolutely insane...

Comment: Are you looking only for real solutions or also imaginary ?

Comment: If you want only real solutions, declare `x` as real: `sympy.Symbol("x", real=True)`. But that doesn't seem to improve speed

Comment: You can solve it numerically with `nsolve`. For example, this returns an answer almost immediately (if you solve for reals only): `sympy.nsolve(sympy.sympify('19.9')*sympy.exp(-sympy.sympify('1.257')*x)-275, (-180, 180), solver='bisect')`, but you'll have to choose the bounds `(-180, 180)` yourself and it'll fail if you guess them wrong.

Comment: Thank you @ForceBru that seemed to work!